# c file all i'm getting is an infinite loop

Tags: c, file, file-io, io

Can anyone help me out with the following c program? This is only my second program in c so I have no clue what I'm doing.

I'm trying to create a program in c to read a file "input.txt" and give students' math scores in asterisks based on a student's percent of correct answers

all I'm coming up with is an infinite loop 
of

+:*

-:*

***:*

/:*

input.txt would be similar to below

---

1 *number of students*

Karla *students name*

8 10 *addition score decided by 8/10*

50 80 *subtraction score decided by 50/80*

30 60 *multiplication score decided by 30/60*

2 5 *division score decided by 2/5*

---

with a desired output of

Karla

+:  * * * * * * * *

-:  * * * * * *

*:  * * * * *

/:  * * * *

---

my code

```
int num; 
char name; 
int sum;
int cur;
int i;
int avg; 

//call file
FILE*ifp=fopen("input.txt","r");
fscanf(ifp,"%d",&num);
for (i=0;i=num;i++){
        fscanf(ifp,"%c",&name);
        printf("%c",&name);
        for(sum=0;sum<=4;sum++){
            fscanf(ifp,"%d",&cur);
            scanf(cur,"%d %d")
            avg=%d/%d;
            if (sum==1)
                printf("+:");
            else if (sum==2)
                printf("-:");
            else if (sum==3)
                printf("*:");
            else if (sum==4)
                printf("/:");
            if (avg==1)
                printf("**********\n");
            else if (avg>=.9)
                printf("*********\n");
            else if (avg>=.8)
                printf("********\n");
            else if (avg>=.7)
                printf("*******\n");
            else if (avg>=.6)
                printf("******\n");
            else if (avg>=.5)
                printf("*****\n");
            else if (avg>=.4)
                printf("****\n");
            else if (avg>=.3)
                printf("***\n");
            else if (avg>=.2)
                printf("**\n");
            else if (avg>=.1)
                printf("*\n");
            else
                printf("\n");
        }
}
//close file
fclose(ifp);
return 0;
```

If anyone could help me out i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: have you tried running this in the debugger?

Comment: better use 1) ``++i`` instead of ``i++`` 2) ``1 == sum`` instead of ``sum == 1``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following For Loop:

```
for(i = 0, i < 10; i++)
{
   DoSomething();
}
```

The order that this executes is:

- run i = 0;
- run i < 10; if the result is "True" keep going.  If the result is "False", leave the loop. Because i is 0 the first time around, and 0 is less than 10, the result is true. Keep going
- run DoSomething();
- run i++
- go back to "run i < 10; if the result is "True". . .

In your case, instead of checking if i is equal to num, you're actually assigning num to i.  Because C treats 0 as "False" and anything else as "True", and because the "result" of i = 10 is 10 (see sidebar1) the computer evaluates i = 10 as "True" so the loop keep going

This is a pretty easy mistake to make in C because the compiler won't warn you about it.  Static analysis tools like Lint will, but that's another story.

**In Conclusion**, you probably want "i = num" to be "i < num" or "i <= num" or some other conditional statement.

**Sidebar1** This property allows you to chain assigns like a = b = c = 10.  The result of c = 10 is 10 so that gets assigned to b.  The result of b = 10 is 10 so that gets assigned to a.

Answer (score 2):

Your infinite loop is because of your outer loop conditional:
change `for (i=0;i=num;i++)` to `for (i=0;i<num;i++)`

As it is, you're just assigning i to num each time, hence the infinite loop.

EDIT:
I should also point out that you have a syntax error on your lines

```
scanf(cur,"%d %d")
avg=%d/%d;
```

And that your `avg` variable is declared as an int, and as such you'll be performing integer division, which likely won't act as you expect; that is, you'll only get whole numbers, so your subsequent conditionals will be largely meaningless. You should make it into a float or double and cast one of your operands to be floating point

Comment: I think there must be `i < num` :)

Comment: Probably `i < num` is more appropriate.

Comment: for what i need to do i changed it to '(i=0;i<=num;i++)' however still getting loop

Comment: is that the code you're running? As it stands it wouldn't compile, due to your line scanf(cur,"%d %d") avg=%d/%d; I'd suggest putting your actual code up that you're running so we can get down to the nitty-gritty